# Can't connect to Hub

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, signalr

In my server side, I just have a simple server side made of MVC

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string platform, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.messageReceived(platform, message);
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

My windows phone client

```
public class Client
{
    private readonly string _platform;
    private readonly HubConnection _connection;
    private readonly IHubProxy _proxy;

    public event EventHandler<string> OnMessageReceived;

    public Client(string platform)
    {
        _platform = platform;
        _connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost");
        _proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("Chat");

    }

    public async Task Connect()
    {
         await _connection.Start();

        _proxy.On("messageReceived", (string platform, string message) =>
        {
            if (OnMessageReceived != null)
                OnMessageReceived(this, string.Format("{0}: {1}", platform, message));
        });

        await Send("Connected");
    }

    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return _proxy.Invoke("Send", _platform, message);
    }
}
```

In my **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
_client = new Client("Windows");
```

When I invoke `Connect` after I deployed my `Hub` it throws an exception of with a response of

`{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Length: 0
}}`

Am I missing something here? I also checked [reference](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting#connection) on how to trouble shoot but I seem to be okay with their guidelines.

Comment: don't you need the full url for the proxy on the client side?

Comment: @AD.Net I tried that one too, didn't work.

Comment: Do you have the assembly attribute `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]`

Comment: @ahmelsayed Tried that, no luck.

Comment: Are you using IIS or IISExpress??

Comment: @ahmelsayed IISExpress

Comment: IISExpress usually runs your site on a port other than 80. find out which port and try `_connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:<PORT>");`

Comment: @ahmelsayed I tried that one too. Didn't work.

Comment: okay, I would use IIS instead of IISExpress. Enable FREB, look at where the 404 is coming from. Try connecting from a simple C# Console app to eliminate any possible issues with Windows Phone SDKs. and see if your request to localhost is ever making it to the server. and make sure you follow all the steps here[1], sorry I can't think of anything else wrong here, maybe someone else would help [1]http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Comment: @ahmelsayed It's working fine even with IISExpress, samples from SignalR is working even the web. But with Windows Phone, it doesn't work. Or any .NET client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone 8 emulator is a virtual machine. This means that "localhost" references the VM/phone, not the host machine running IIS/IISExpress.

You can connect to the host machine using its hostname or IP address.

If you decide to stick with IIS Express, you will need to configure Windows Firewall to accept inbound requests on whatever port IIS Express is running on.

The guide on [How to connect to a local web service from the Windows Phone 8 emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) focuses on WCF, but applies equally to SignalR.

Comment: Thank you, I've figure it out since I can't connect with the browser with my hostname/ipaddress.